# Extremely slow INSERT query when database not local

Tags: python, sql, mysql, pythonanywhere

I'm adding data to a `MySQL 8` database on PythonAnywhere. I'm doing this via a `python 3.10` script run in `VSCode` using an `SSH Tunnel`. When I add the data it takes approximately 50 seconds to add 275 rows, data in json format is 750kb so total likely a bit less than that. No error messages.

When I use the same script to add the identical data to a database on my local machine it takes 0.2 seconds. Playing with batch sized between commits reduced the total time from 75 seconds to 50 seconds, but that's the best I've got. It's for a web scraper, when the full thing is running it could have a few hundred to a few thousand rows to add/remove, so it's not tenable to leave it like this. With performance this poor I must be doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is. The timer is wrapped around the insert query, it doesn't include the ssh connection time etc.

What's going on here?

The table columns are as follows, so far now indexes being used:

```
"listingID int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
types VARCHAR(11), 
town VARCHAR(255), 
postcode CHAR(5), 
price INT UNSIGNED, 
agent VARCHAR(50), 
ref VARCHAR(30), 
bedrooms SMALLINT UNSIGNED, 
rooms SMALLINT UNSIGNED, 
plot MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED, 
size MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED, 
link_url VARCHAR(1024), 
description VARCHAR(14000), 
photos TEXT, 
photos_hosted TEXT, 
gps POINT, 
id VARCHAR(80), 
types_original VARCHAR(30)"
```

The functions adding the data are below. As I said it completes in 0.2 seconds locally so I don't think I'm doing anything too bad there, even if it's not perfect. `listings` is a list of dictionaries. The weird use of dictionaries for the inserts is because I was using named placeholders with mysql.connector, but I had to switch to MySQLdb due to another problem with accessing the database, and it doesn't permit named placeholders.

```
def insert_data_to_table(cursor, table_name, columns_list, values_dict, gps_string):
    # Creates a string of csv %s placeholders for the values to be inserted
    placeholders = ", ".join(f"%s" for _ in values_dict.keys())

    # Creates a string of columns to be inserted
    columns = ", ".join(columns_list)

    # If GPS data is provided, insert specific string into query. Else build query without GPS sub string.
    if gps_string:
        insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (gps, {columns}) VALUES ({gps_string}, {placeholders})"
    else:
        insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders})"

    cursor.execute(insert_query, tuple(values_dict.values()))

def add_listings(cursor, listings):
    print("Adding data...")
    counter = 0
    for listing in listings:
    # Committing every 50 rows rather than after each row reduces time by approx 33%, minimal differences 
     between 20, 50, 100 etc.
        if counter > 50:
            print("Commit", counter)
            db.commit()
            counter = 0
        columns_list = []

        values_dict = {key: None for key in listing if key != "gps"}

        if listing.get("gps") is None:
            gps_string = None
        elif isinstance(listing.get("gps"), list):
            gps_string = f"ST_GeomFromText('POINT({round(listing['gps'][0], 6)} {round(listing['gps'][1], 6)})', 4326)"

        for key in values_dict:
            if isinstance(listing.get(key), list):
                values_dict[key] = ":;:".join([str(x) for x in listing[key]])
            else:
                values_dict[key] = listing.get(key)
            columns_list.append(key)

        insert_data_to_table(cursor, table_name, columns_list, values_dict, gps_string)
        counter += 1
    db.commit()
```

Comment: You could check to see if the cursor''s `executemany` method batches values (rather than just sending a separate statement for each set of values).  Or you could generate the statements yourself `INSERT INTO tbl (a, b) VALUES (%s, %s), (%s, %s), ...`.  That might reduce the number of network transmissions that need to be made.

Comment: This was the main issue, thank you for spotting it and letting me know.

Comment: How many rows in the table?  (`SHOW TABLE STATUS`)  What `INDEXes` are there?

Comment: Please provide a sample of the _generated_ SQL.

Comment: My experience with multi-row `INSERTs` is that you get 10x speed up with a batch of 100 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue turned out to be my inefficient code. By rewriting it to use `executemany` it reduced the time taken from 50s to 5s.

Also the database is hosted in USA and I'm in France, which probably doesn't help.

Comment: For hopping over an ocean, minimizing the _number_ of SQL statements is the main optimization.  Probably more than 100ms overhead _per query_.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand your solution. Upload the data file to the target server and run the migration from crontab if it is possible. Perhaps it will be faster.

Comment: I was trying to avoid uploading the file directly. So far I have been running the scraper locally (it outputs a json file, and tens to hundreds of small images in a specific file tree), then pushing it to github, and pulling from PythonAnywhere as the means to transmit the data. It works, but a bit of a pain. Also the ever growing .git folder is eating my available space. I wanted to use a database that I can update automatically when the scraper runs locally), so that I can stop using github as a means to transfer. Transferring the file to PA first means all the same extra steps, plus images

Comment: 100ms per ocean hop.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are hosting the server with PythonAnywhere? If you are using a free beginner plan, it would probably have insufficient CPU and bandwidth for your task. It would be too slow.

My guess is the bandwidth for the server on pythonanywhere is not enough. If you are finding a free solution for hosting, you can try other companies that provide free hosting (free tier)

I personally use AWS, it has a free tier for 12 months. There's probably more out there and you can google more about it.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying. It's a good point - in this case I am using a paid account, albeit the lowest tier one, but it does say that it should be enough for a typical 100,000 hit / day website (I haven't released the url yet so have zero users). I was hoping to have the database local to the web app for speed reasons rather than hosted elsewhere, but only if it actually works. I'll look into AWS as an alternative, thank you. I also posted on the PythonAnywhere forum, a team member has said they will look into it next week. I'll update if I get a concrete answer / solution. Cheers again :)